# Move Groupwise POA from SLES to Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sles, novell, groupwise

I'm attempting to move a GroupWise POA from a crippled SLES cluster to a 2008R2 server, it appears all the binaries meet the requirements, but where the documentation fails me are for a few questions:

1) Is a local installation of eDirectory required on the Windows server?

2) There are references to using a DBcopy utility when migrating TO Linux due to filename case changes, is this a concern going the other direction? I suspect not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No need for an eDir replica on Windows, but you do need an eDirectory replica somewhere.  eDir will run on Windows, Solaris, AIX, or Linux.  (And still on Netware if you want too).

2) The issue with case sensitive file names has to do with how Netware file systems (TFS or NSS) handle case sensitivity.  They are case remembering but not case sensitive per se.  So when you move to a file system that is really case sensitive (like ext3fs, reiser, etc) on Linux, you have a problem.  So DBCopy has an option to fix this up on the fly.  (Ironically if you are running OES2 on Linux and just remount your NSS file system on Linux, there are no worries).

Once you are already on Linux you should be fine in terms of case.

Side note:  Linux PO's perform much better than on Windows.